# ruby: how to do inheritance or compostion

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance, composition

I'm trying to DRY some code.
How to to do composition and/or inheritance with ruby using this piece of code.

```
module Ns4
  module Maps
    module StrokeStyle
      class RedOutline
        def self.strokeColor
          "red"
        end

        def self.strokeWeight
          4
        end
      end

      class Random
        def self.strokeColor
          [ "#808080", "#909090" ].sample(1)[0]
        end

        def self.strokeWeight
          4
        end
      end

      class Transparent
        def self.strokeColor
          "transparent"
        end

        def self.strokeWeight
          0
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Basically I want to reduce the duplication of logic wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of something along these lines:

```
module Ns4
  module Maps
    module StrokeStyle
      module StrokeHelper
        def self.included(base)
          base.singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, *%i(strokeColor strokeWeight))
        end
      end
      class RedOutline
        include StrokeHelper
      end
      class Random
        include StrokeHelper
      end
      class Transparent
        include StrokeHelper
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now you have a setter and getter for both `strokeColor` and `strokeWeight` in each class:

```
Ns4::Maps::StrokeStyle::RedOutline.strokeColor = 'red'
Ns4::Maps::StrokeStyle::RedOutline.strokeColor
#=> "red"
Ns4::Maps::StrokeStyle::RedOutline.strokeWeight = 4
Ns4::Maps::StrokeStyle::RedOutline.strokeWeight
#=> 4
```

Comment: `base.singleton_class.send(:attr_accessor, *%i|strokeColor strokeWeight|)` :) Also, I doubt it would work with random array element.

Comment: @mudasobwa agree.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to really DRY it:

```
METHODS = %i|strokeColor strokeWeight|
DECLARATIONS = { 
  :RedOutline => [-> { 'red' }, 4], 
  :Random => [-> { %w|#808080 #909090|.sample }, 4], 
  :Transparent => ['transparent', 0]
}


module Ns4 
  module Maps
    module StrokeStyle
      DECLARATIONS.each do |klazz, props|
        StrokeStyle.const_set(klazz, Module.new do
          METHODS.zip(props).each do |(m, p)| 
            define_method m do p.is_a?(Proc) ? p.call : p end
          end
          module_function *METHODS
        end)
      end 
    end 
  end 
end

puts Ns4::Maps::StrokeStyle::RedOutline.strokeColor
#⇒ red
puts Ns4::Maps::StrokeStyle::Random.strokeColor
#⇒ #808080
puts Ns4::Maps::StrokeStyle::Transparent.strokeColor
#⇒ transparent
```

Adding new methods now as easy as adding new `Hash` elements.

Comment: this is barely compliant with KISS principle but is very cool :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko this is exactly what I call KISS :)

Comment: Perfect, perfetto, parfait, perfekt, perfecto, 完ぺき, 完美, 완전한 ! (Upvoted earlier.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Without a doubt I would opt for one comment like this instead of ten upvotes.